# mysql error : Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_5115_0.MYI

Tags: partitioning, mysql, tmp, tmpfs

Query failed by reason : `Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_5115_0.MYI`

i read that it may be realted to disk space issue but i ma not sure how that is as `df -h` returns

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5        69G  5.7G   60G   9% /
udev            7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  256K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /run/shm
overflow        1.0M  8.0K 1016K   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1       223M   24M  187M  12% /boot
/dev/sdb1        16T  2.9T   13T  19% /storage
```

Keep in mind `/storage` is not involved in any way with any mysql dbs

sugestions?

Comment: @Jos Thank You So much dear. You saved my lot of time. I just gone through the same issue.
Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

At some point in time, your disk ran out of space, and some space was allocated by mounting a virtual disk called "overflow" at /tmp. Now MySQL tries to create a file in /tmp but it can't.
To remedy this, do
`sudo umount overflow`
I got this idea from [here](http://jarrodoverson.com/blog/overflow-filesystem-in-linux/).